# Is it possible to avoid surrogate primary key in OneToOne relation and reuse foreign key as id?

Tags: hibernate, orm

One entity `ObjDetails` is optional to `Obj` in `OneToOne` relation.

I don't see benefits of using surrogate primary key in `ObjDetails`, like that is recommended in official docs and numerous tutorials:

```
@Entity
public class ObjDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Obj obj;
}
```

Relation is such that it is not possible to have `ObjDetails` without `Obj`.

Can `Obj` be used as primary key in `ObjDetails`? What is the syntax to express this?

```
@Entity
public class ObjDetails {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    private Obj obj;
}
```

Can we avoid declaring object type of `Obj` in `ObjDetails` but to express that `Long id` from `ObjDetails` is the same as in `Obj`?

```
@Entity
public class ObjDetails {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    private Long id;
}
```

Comment: Why oh why don't people read the docupentation? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a stripped copy of example from official docs:

```
@Entity
public static class Person  {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public static class PersonDetails  {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Person person;
}
```

Essential part is to keep both primitive `@Id` reference and typed `Person` reference marked by `@OneToOne` and most importantly by `@MapsId`.

It is called **Derived Identifiers**. Thanks JB for pointing to docs.